Using element.children to move node before and after
I have a simple javascript to move an element before and after its siblings. All works fine with moving the element to be inserted before the element before it but when moving to AFTER its next sibling it jumps 2 siblings. If I use [x+1] it doesn't do anything, I assume because I'm inserting before the next sibling keeping it where it is. What am I doing wrong here? I know I'm missing some simple logic but I can't figure it out.
//divID variable is the id of the parent element that contains the arrowLeft and arrowRight elements.

let widgBox = document.getElementById('wBox')
let widgBoxArray = widgBox.children
arrowLeft.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    //this works as intended
    for(let x=0; x<widgBoxArray.length; x++){
      if(widgBoxArray[x].id===divID && x !== 0){
        widgBox.insertBefore(widgBoxArray[x],widgBoxArray[x-1])
      }
    }
  })
  arrowRight.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    //this is does not work as intended
    for(let x=0; x<widgBoxArray.length; x++){
      if(widgBoxArray[x].id===divID && x !== widgBoxArray.length-1){
        widgBox.insertBefore(widgBoxArray[x],widgBoxArray[x+2])
      }
    }
  })


Please provide the HTML that is needed for this.

Seems to work as intended. https://jsfiddle.net/uceowj8s/

BTW instead of checking x !== 0 and x !== widgBoxArray.length-1 you could just adjust your for loops, ie for (let x = 1; ...) and for (let x = 0; x < x<widgBoxArray.length - 1; ...) respectively

Or you could get rid of the for loops and do let x = widgBoxArray.findIndex(e => e.id === divID) instead ...

The problem is that your loop continues after you did the insertion (the move), and the next iteration will find the divID element there again.
You should break from the loop once you have a match. Also, x+2 might be a non-existing element, and to avoid that you could insert the next sibling (x+1) before the current element (x):
    for(let x=0; x<widgBoxArray.length; x++){
      if(widgBoxArray[x].id===divID && x < widgBoxArray.length-1){
        // Move the next sibling before the current node
        widgBox.insertBefore(widgBoxArray[x+1], widgBoxArray[x]);
        break; // Quit the loop to avoid more matches
      }
    }

It would however be more natural to not loop at all, and just find the element with a DOM method:
    const child = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (child?.nextElementSibling) {
        widgBox.insertBefore(child.nextElementSibling, child);
    }

Snippet:


const divID = "target";

const [arrowLeft, arrowRight] = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const widgBox = document.getElementById('wBox')

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const child = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (child?.previousElementSibling) {
        widgBox.insertBefore(child, child.previousElementSibling);
    }
})

arrowRight.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    const child = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (child?.nextElementSibling) {
        widgBox.insertBefore(child.nextElementSibling, child);
    }
})
span { border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
#target { background: yellow }
<div id="wBox">
<span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span id="target">Target</span><span>D</span><span>E</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button id="left">◄</button><button id="right">►</button>
</div>



If however, as you indicate in below comment, you need the index x for other purposes, then you need the loop. It might be nice to use findIndex for that purpose:


const divID = "target";

const [arrowLeft, arrowRight] = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const widgBox = document.getElementById('wBox');
const widgBoxArray = widgBox.children;

const moveLeft = x => widgBoxArray[x] && widgBoxArray[x-1] 
                   && widgBox.insertBefore(widgBoxArray[x], widgBoxArray[x-1]);

const getIndex = () => [...widgBoxArray].findIndex(child => child.id === divID);

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', () => moveLeft(getIndex()));

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', () => moveLeft(getIndex()+1));
span { border: 1px solid; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; }
#target { background: yellow }
<div id="wBox">
<span>A</span><span>B</span><span>C</span><span id="target">Target</span><span>D</span><span>E</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <button id="left">◄</button><button id="right">►</button>
</div>




Marked correct! Thank you, that was a silly mistake on my part. Adding the break solved it. FYI, I'm using the array method because I save the position on the page in a database so it can be rebuilt in the same order, so its easy now to just update the db with the index position.

You're welcome. I can see that having the index x could serve some other purposes. In that case, using findIndex might still be more elegant.
